# Закрасить части графика в полярных координатах

Tags: python

Нужно закрасить часть кругового графика каким-то опредленным цветом.
Пробовал такой код:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
plt.axes(projection = 'polar')
  
azimuths = np.radians(np.linspace(0, 360, 15))
zeniths = np.arange(0, 120, 8)
plt.polar(azimuths, zeniths, 'g.')

X1 = np.zeros((1,len(azimuths)))
X1[:]=100
X2 = np.zeros((1,len(azimuths)))
X2[:]=80

plt.fill_between(rad, X1, X2, color='cyan')
# display the polar plot
plt.show()
```

Но для строчки plt.fill_between(rad, X1, X2, color='cyan') выходит ошибка

```
ValueError: 'y1' is not 1-dimensional
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно исправить?

Comment: NameError: name 'rad' is not defined

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27229826/fill-between-two-polar-curves-with-matplotlib-fill-between

Comment: как добавить цвет  plt.fill_between(theta, 80, 100, alpha=0.2, color='magneta')

Comment: подскажите, пожалуйста, у меня все в ошибке

Comment: А как соединенить точки графика?